# Python, multithreading worker queue: what's the right design to avoid deadlock when workers might wait for other to complete?

Tags: python, multithreading, deadlock

I have a typical scenario where I have a finite number of threads/workers which are forever fetching & processing tasks from a queue. Those tasks are typical read > process > save. Turns out some of those tasks can themselves add to the task queue and will wait for the the task they supply to finish before releasing (a typical .join() operation).

In this scenario, we could very well reach a deadlock where the finite number of workers are all allocated and busy with tasks that are themself waiting for other tasks to complete - but with no worker left, they never do and we are deadlock. For example, 5 worker are available, they immediatly pull 5 tasks that fires 15 more tasks and wait for them to complete - they will never be completed since the only 5 workers available are blocked.

Obviously with enough workers this will be less likely to happen but this isn't very satisfying (we could very well have 200 workers polling 20 new tasks each). Some workaround i thought about - but none seem elegant

- I could create a separate queue / pool of workers for those secondary tasks that do not depend on other tasks (or have each worker create its own separate queue / worker pool when needed)
- I could make the tasks non blocking (partially saving results to database, with the other completing the results but the db being in an unstable state doesn't sound good)

Any idea on the right design for this scenario?

Comment: Make tasks non blocking. You can utilize async/await, one of the reasons it was invented was to solve the same problem. I don't understand the comment about "db being in an unstable state". What's "unstable" about an unfinished task? That's a valid and stable state. Perhaps you will have to create some cleaning mechanism, yes, it requires more work. But it is a good idea. Also you may want to use some library for that, do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - will look at async/wait. You're right you can do without the consumer/producer queue design. Probably my best best. On the DB side, yes i would have to flag that the row isn't complete so that it isn't used by a consumer on the other side but i thinking it's just moving the problem and exposing it to others.

Comment: I had some "fun" with async/await. On that use case, it turns out you have to implement the same queue (producer/consumer) design with a finite number of consumer workers so it doesn't help - i still get deadlocks. In retrospect, I can see where async/await nicely improve on threading when you have a predefined list of tasks to run but in the queue setup, i just find the complexity / code overhead just not worth it (and seriously ... code readibility?!). I went with my option 1 of letting task create some other threads...

Comment: your option 1 is very shortsighted. What if at one point your secondary tasks become dependent on some other tasks? Also, code readability or comolexity is only as big as you make it. It isn't a property of async/await.